# Error parsing text-format opencv_tensorflow.GraphDef

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, protocol-buffers

I want to use the function `cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow` giving as parameters .pb and .pbtxt files in order to make predictions from a model trained in python but I get this error:

```
Error parsing text-format opencv_tensorflow.GraphDef: 18749:5: Unknown enumeration value of "DT_VARIANT" for field "type".
```

I tried different tf versions but the error is still present, did I create a wrong .pbtxt file?

Comment: What version of opencv, python and tensorflow did you try so far?

Comment: @Proko I'm currently using tensorflow==2.2.0 and keras==2.4.3 with python 3.8.8.          Concerning opencv I' m using OpenCV(4.5.3).                                                                    I've also tried with tensorflow==2.4.0 and 2.6.0 but I didn't try with different version of python in order to keep the one used in training phase.